# Dealing with state

Tags: scala

I am working on something that involves the observer pattern. A simple version of that looks like this:

```
private var listeners = Set.empty[A => Unit]

def addListener(listener: A => Unit):() => Unit = {
  listeners += listener
  () => listeners -= listener
}
```

In my code I have something that deals a bit more abstract with these types of connections. The following class will allow you to connect and disconnect things. It also allows you to disconnect from inside a `connect` method.

To allow that kind of interaction I created the following class.

```
class Connection {
  type Disconnect = () => Unit

  private var disconnectHolder: Option[Disconnect] = None

  private var connecting = false
  private var pendingDisconnect = false

  def connect(connect: () => Disconnect): Unit = {
    disconnect()
    disconnectHolder = Some {
      connecting = true
      val disconnect = connect()
      connecting = false
      disconnect
    }
    if (pendingDisconnect) disconnect()
  }

  def disconnect(): Unit =
    if (connecting) pendingDisconnect = true
    else {
      disconnectHolder foreach { disconnect =>
        disconnectHolder = None
        disconnect()
      }
      pendingDisconnect = false
    }
}
```

The code is used like this:

```
protected def connectToSource():Disconnect = ...
protected def activate(): Unit = connection.connect(connectToSource)
protected def deactivate(): Unit = connection.disconnect()
```

Where `connectToSource` has different implementations. A few examples:

```
// Filtered[A](source: EventStream[A], p: A => Boolean)
def connectToSource() = source addListener (a => if (p(a)) emit(a))

// Mapped[A, B](source: EventStream[A], f: A => B)
def connectToSource() = source addListener (f andThen emit)

// Merged[A](sources: Seq[EventStream[A]])
def connectToSource() = {
  val disconnects = sources.map(_ addListener emit)
  () => disconnects foreach (_ apply ())
}
```

And more complex examples:

```
// Flattened[A, B](source: EventStream[A], f: A => EventStream[B])
def connectToSource() = {
  val innerConnection = new Connection

  val disconnectSource =
    source addListener { a =>
      innerConnection.connect(() => f(a) addListener emit)
    }

  () => {
    innerConnection.disconnect()
    disconnectSource()
  }
}
```

Note that this code does not need to be thread safe. There must at least be one mutable variable in there. I am wondering in what ways I can structure the code to reduce the number of variables and improve the readability.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what the preface about the observer pattern has to do with the rest of your question about the `Connection` class.

Comment: @200_success I have added a few usage examples, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

- You should make use of `type Disconnect = () => Unit` for the returned type of:

  ```
   def addListener(listener: A => Unit):() => Unit
  ```
- Instead of `() => Disconnect` you should probably define some `Subscription` type, which has an `unsubscribe()` method.
- If your code is single threaded, you don't need `connecting` and `pendingDisconnect` and the associated complex logic at all.  A single thread can only ever be in `connect` or in `disconnect`, but never both.
- Try not to use an argument which has the same name as the method and which is also a method itself; see `def connect(connect)` which calls `connect()` (the argument `connect`, not itself) in its body.   It's quite confusing.
- The observer pattern is being deprecated in favor of reactive programming (see [RxScala](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala)), where instead of observers you have observables, which are streams of data.

Comment: What if the passed in `connect` method causes a call to `disconnect`? As for the observer pattern being deprecated, I am working on a FRP library, all FRP libraries use the observer pattern internally.

Comment: Why is it better to define a `Subscription` type instead of a simple `() => Unit` method?

Comment: From the documentation of `RxJava` (used by RxScala): "It extends the observer pattern ..."

Comment: About `connect` causing a `disconnect`: 1) You always disconnect at the start, I guess to avoid connecting twice, but it would make more sense to just skip the method body if it is already connected.  2) If it is single threaded and you get rid of `connecting` and `pendingConnect`, `connect` will never trigger a disconnect.

Comment: `Subscription` is just for readability.  It's really not obvious what `() => Unit` does.

Comment: Reactive programming extends the observer pattern, but it is not the same.  The emphasis is more on the observables than the observers (push rather than pull).

Comment: How is `observable.subscribe(subsciber)` different from `subject.registerObserver(observer)`?

Comment: Look at the api in more detail.  90% of the code is about all you can do with Observables.

Comment: I think this discussion is going nowhere. It seems you are trying to convince me to use a reactive library while I am writing one myself. At the core of every reactive library that allows monadic operations a mutable list of observers is kept. I am following the same pattern as the paper [Deprecating the Observer Pattern](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/176887/files/DeprecatingObservers2012.pdf). Moreover, my original question was about the state and how I could deal with it differently.

Comment: Well, maybe you could have mentioned that before.  They mention in the second sentence of that paper that it is reactive programming.  I only mentioned reactive programming because I was trying to help; I was aware it was not directly related to your question.

Comment: If you are doing your framework for fun, good for you, but if you are doing this for your employer, maybe you should just use RxScala since it will save an awful lot of time ($$$).